# NodeJS match with regex gets last word than after space

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, match

```
var prefix = '.'
var str = '.kick blah 1 2 3'.match(`${prefix}kick (.*) (.*)`);

console.log(str)
```

result:
`[ 'blah 1 2', '3', index: 0, input: '.kick blah 1 2 3', ]`

I wanted result to be
`[ 'blah', '1 2 3', index: 0, input: '.kick blah 1 2 3', ]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make the first group non-greedy, or else "." will keep matching..

Change the regex to `${prefix}kick (.*?) (.*)`